# Could not find stored procedure 'insertForum'

Tags: c#, asp.net

Trying to insert into my database from the web page but am shown an error message that the values been inserted cannot be passed on to the database and after debugging the error message it became clear to me that "insertforum" stored procedure cannot be found. What can be done to resolve the issue?

```
public class PostForum
{
    public static int insertForum(int titleid, string question, string posterName,    DateTime datetime, string username)
    {
        int rowsAffected = 0;

        using (SqlConnection connection = ConnectionManager.GetDatabaseConnection())
        {
            SqlCommand cmmand = new SqlCommand("insertForum", connection);
            cmmand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

            cmmand.Parameters.Add("@titleid", SqlDbType.Int).Value = titleid;
            cmmand.Parameters.Add("@question", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = question;
            cmmand.Parameters.Add("@posterName", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = posterName;
            cmmand.Parameters.Add("@datetime", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = datetime;
            cmmand.Parameters.Add("@username", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = username;

            cmmand.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }

        return rowsAffected;
    }
}
```

Here is my connection string:

```
    <connectionStrings>
    <add name="nn008ConnectionString" connectionString="Data Source=SQL-SERVER;Initial     Catalog=nn008;Integrated Security=True"
  providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

Comment: Create a stored procedure named insertForum?

Comment: Or you don't have a stored procedure named `insertForum` or you are connecting to a different database. Could you show your connection string?

Comment: As @JDB and Steve said, you either dont have a stored procedure named insertForum or you are pointing the wrong Database

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is too localized and unlikely to help other users.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I simply created a stored procedure for insertForum on management studio and that fixed the error. Below is how i solved the error:

CREATE PROCEDURE insertForum
(
@titleid int,
@question varchar(200),
..........
.........
)
AS
INSERT forum
(
titleid,
question,
.......
.......
)
Values
(
titleid,
question,
........
.......
)
RETURN